# Jquery function needs to cancel other functions first

Tags: jquery, animation

The issue that I am having is the I have a div where there are three hidden span tags (used as labels) with jquery I use mouseover function to animate one of those labels.

I am wondering if there is a way to stop/cancel a function that is already running. i.e, if I quickly move to a second mouseover event, the animations seem to queue, meaning when I have moved away there could be animations still occurring.

Ideally, a mouseover event on a new button would kill any currently running animations in there.

Comment: Can we see some code that you've written so we can help with the jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function.  This stops the current animation.

If you want to remove all the currently queued elements, you have to pass a first argument of `true`. If you want to jump to the end of the current animation (generally a good idea) you should pass a second argument of `true`.

So your call will probably look a bit like this:

```
$('#someEl').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this)
        .stop(true, true) // stop any currently existing animations 
        .animate({        // and then start a new one
            marginLeft: '20px'
        }, 250);
});
```

Comment: With the margin left animation being what happens after you stop everything?

Comment: Thanks. Although now on my page it doesn't seem to be stopping. i.e. I can still roll across them, and when im over the third I still see the second popping up and staying

Comment: I have accepted the answer as Im sure it is correct and something else must be going on

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can call the .stop() method to stop any running animations on the matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, There is one function in jquery. Try this  :

```
$('#divId').hover(function() {
$(this).find('#img1').stop(true, true).slideUp();
$(this).find('#img2').stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function() {
$(this).find('#img1').stop(true, true).slideDown();
$(this).find('#img2').stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```